# Swagger/NSwag keep decimal datatype

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle, nswag

I do have my .net data classes, containing a few decimal fields (for example `quantity`). I generate an openapi.json out of it running dotnet swagger.

```
...
"quantity": {
            "type": "number",
            "format": "double"
          },
...
```

As you can see it produces a type "number" with format "double". And nswag creates a client, where the field is a double too.

Can I configure somehow to set format as decimal? When I edit the openapi.json manually, the nswag creation produces a decimal as expected.

I tried to add this annotation, but it doesn't change anything: `[JsonSchema(JsonObjectType.Number, Format = "decimal")]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding this line into your `.AddSwaggerGen()` definition

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
  c.MapType<decimal>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "number", Format = "decimal" });
  // ...
```

Comment: And if the domain type is decimal?, use c.MapType<decimal?>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "number", Format="decimal", Nullable = true });